# Integrate Moodle with SuitCRM

Tags: moodle, suitecrm

I want to integrate Moodle with SuitCRM.  I've installed both Myddleware and SuiteCRM and configured it correctly.  Within SuiteCRM I created all the modules and fields but somehow does not work.  What am I doing wrong?  Please help!!!

This is the error message I m getting:

"Transaction commit failed because the transaction has been marked for rollback only. (/var/www/html/empowerme.school/myddleware/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/ConnectionException.php line 12)"

Comment: Hi Dimpels, this looks more a Myddleware question, I am not familiar with the integration software but I think you should tag it in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you getting back to me.

Comment: On a different note.  How can I integrate Moodle and SuiteCRM without Myddleware?  Maybe through API's, but how?

Comment: wow, thats a new question and  a large one. I used moodle but never the API, the first thing will be to model what you want to integrate. Which module you use to integrate Courses? maybe opportunities? then do the same thing with all the moodle entities you need in suitecrm, like teachers and students. After that you can use either the API or something like talend/pentaho kettle to integrate either with API or direct DB access. Its not trivial! so always try something already working.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I have created my own modules in SuiteCRM which basically mimics Moodle.  But I can't get Moodle to update of push information from Moodle to SuiteCRM.  I tried Myddleware for this but it also does not push the information through.

Comment: try installing the webhook plugin or use zapier to push on-demand data.

Comment: Hi, a webhook in Moodle or a webhook in SuiteCRM?

Comment: you will need both hooks to have a bi-directional sync